# How do I store a contentfile into ImageField in Django

Tags: mysql, django

I am trying to convert an image  uploaded by user into a PDF , and then store it into an `ImageField` in a `mysql database` ,using a `form`, but am facing an error when trying to store the **PDF** into the database

**My views.py is:**

```
from django.core.files.storage import FileSystemStorage
from PIL import Image
import io
from io import BytesIO
from django.core.files.uploadedfile import InMemoryUploadedFile
from django.core.files.base import ContentFile

def formsubmit(request):                        #submits the form
    docs = request.FILES.getlist('photos')
    print(docs)
    section = request.POST['section']
    for x in docs:
        fs = FileSystemStorage()
        print(type(x.size))
        img = Image.open(io.BytesIO(x.read()))
        imgc = img.convert('RGB')
        pdfdata = io.BytesIO()
        imgc.save(pdfdata,format='PDF')
        thumb_file = ContentFile(pdfdata.getvalue())
        filename = fs.save('photo.pdf', thumb_file)
        linkobj = Link(link = filename.file, person = Section.objects.get(section_name = section), date = str(datetime.date.today()), time = datetime.datetime.now().strftime('%H:%M:%S'))
        linkobj.save()
        count += 1
        size += x.size  
    return redirect('index')
```

**My models.py:**

```
    class Link(models.Model):
    id      = models.BigAutoField(primary_key=True)
    person  = models.ForeignKey(Section, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    link    = models.ImageField(upload_to= 'images', default = None)
    date    = models.CharField(max_length=80, default = None)
    time    = models.CharField(max_length=80,default = None)
```

**Error I am getting is:**

```
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'file'
```

**Other methods I have tried:**

```
1) linkobj = Link(link = thumb_file, person = Section.objects.get(section_name = section), date = str(datetime.date.today()), time = datetime.datetime.now().strftime('%H:%M:%S'))
```

**RESULT OF ABOVE METHOD**:
1)The `thumb_file` doesnt throw an error, rather it stores nothing in the database

**Points I have noticed:**

1)The file is being stored properly into the media folder, ie: I can see the pdf getting stored in the media folder

How do I solve this? Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't (basically ever) need to initialize a Storage by yourself. This holds especially true since the storage for the field might not be a `FileSystemStorage` at all, but could e.g. be backed by S3.

Something like

```
import datetime
import io

from PIL import Image
from django.core.files.base import ContentFile


def convert_image_to_pdf_data(image):
    img = Image.open(io.BytesIO(image.read()))
    imgc = img.convert("RGB")
    pdfdata = io.BytesIO()
    imgc.save(pdfdata, format="PDF")
    return pdfdata.getvalue()


def formsubmit(request):  # submits the form
    photos = request.FILES.getlist("photos")  # list of UploadedFiles
    section = request.POST["section"]
    person = Section.objects.get(section_name=section)
    date = str(datetime.date.today())
    time = datetime.datetime.now().time("%H:%M:%S")
    count = 0
    size = 0
    for image in photos:
        pdfdata = convert_image_to_pdf_data(image)
        thumb_file = ContentFile(pdfdata, name="photo.pdf")
        Link.objects.create(
            link=thumb_file,
            person=person,
            date=date,
            time=time,
        )
        count += 1
        size += image.size
    return redirect("index")
```

should be enough here, i.e. using a `ContentFile` for the converted PDF content; the field should deal with saving it into the storage.

(As an aside, why are date and time stored separately as strings? Your database surely has a datetime type...)

Comment: Thanks for the answer, and in regards to the date and time fields, I just have a bad habit of storing them as separate strings , which I definitely need to solve as soon as possible

Answer (score 0):

Ok so I found an answer, to be fair I wont accept my own answer as it doesn't provide an exact answer to the question I asked, rather its a different method, so if anyone does know , please do share so that the community can benefit:

**My Solution:**
Instead of using `ContentFile`, I used `InMemoryUploadedFile`, to store the converted pdf and then moved it into the database( in an `ImageField`)

I am going to be honest, I am not completely sure about why `ContentFile` was not working, but when going through the documentation I found out that :

**The ContentFile class inherits from File, but unlike File it operates on string content (bytes also supported), rather than an actual file.**

Any detailed explanation is welcome

**My new views.py**

```
from django.core.files.storage import FileSystemStorage
from PIL import Image
import io
from io import BytesIO
from django.core.files.uploadedfile import InMemoryUploadedFile
from django.core.files.base import ContentFile
import sys

def formsubmit(request):                        #submits the form
    docs = request.FILES.getlist('photos')
    print(docs)
    section = request.POST['section']
    for x in docs:
        fs = FileSystemStorage()
        print(type(x.size))
        img = Image.open(io.BytesIO(x.read()))
        imgc = img.convert('RGB')
        pdfdata = io.BytesIO()
        imgc.save(pdfdata,format='PDF')
        thumb_file = InMemoryUploadedFile(pdfdata, None, 'photo.pdf', 'pdf',sys.getsizeof(pdfdata), None)
        linkobj = Link(link = thumb_file, person = Section.objects.get(section_name = section), date = str(datetime.date.today()), time = datetime.datetime.now().strftime('%H:%M:%S'))
        linkobj.save()
        count += 1
        size += x.size  
    return redirect('index')
```

If you have a question, you can leave it in the comments and ill try to answer it, Good luck!!!

Comment: Remember ImageFields and FileFields don't actually store the data in the database. They just store a path to your storage.

Comment: @AKX yeah I just figured that out, cant believe I actually thought it stored the whole image there, but I have a question, suppose I get the url/path using the FileSystemStorage, I could theoretically store that into the imageField, thereby removing the need of creating a InMemoryUploadedFIle?